# Request retuning possible gzip

Tags: node.js, request

I have this code:

```
                   var options = { method: 'POST',
                      url: '...',
                      headers: 
                       {
                         'accept-language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
                         'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                         referer: '...',
                         'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                         'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36',
                         'x-csrf-jwt': `${test}`,
                         'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                         origin: '...' },
                      body: `...` };

                    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                      if (error) throw new Error(error);

                      console.log(body);
                    });
```

But, the body is returning incomprehensibly. Look:

```
E�IU�w��Msk�������%&�vj�Xĉ�݌��0�J���Nxֈ��N�����J��{�g�������d�|��l�m�5��5�V�qs0��e�ٮ>VZE�`�`X�DX��Ed?9I�#��SO�C���u�D�<Dmn�O14WEr#�@�6���jY�9FN�p���H�Ox�7n�bt��.Vq�f�_#5��
���jJU����K���8S��)3ns��:X�]G"~� Ϯ3�Q��r�g�I��9�Ar�#�q�Γ~Xcoǋ�}x/#u�R��g/����L���Vs(N��o\���N��:�F�u}��zf�'�dz�'њKB���h��ۻDg��\%5�i�O��)#q�T<9��qT�~v�B�׾4Ň��|�^�k��M��   �� #IYE
```

This only happens with node.js

Was it returning compressed in gzip?

If so, how can I decompress it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `gzip: true` to `options` and remove `accept-encoding` from `options.headers`